# How can we open a file present on remote machine from local machine using FileDialog in swt in java?

Tags: java, server

I want to access a file of remote machine which ip address is `10.11.201.170 .` I want to point FileDialog in `D:` drive of this pc . That is why , I have written the following code :

```
 FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);

        dialog.setFilterPath("//10.11.201.170/d:");

        dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.docx" }); 

        String fileName = dialog.open();
```

But the  FileDialog does not point to D: drive of `10.11.201.170` pc . how can I open  FileDialog  in `D:` drive of the remote pc ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the remoted server a valid network storage? Do you have mapped the D: drive to your client machine? If not you can't access it using a File System API like FileDialog

Comment: How can I map D: drive to my client machine?

Comment: Well it depends. The remote server is a NAS, a SAN, another Windows machine inside the same network? Here is a way to do it in the simplest scenario (sharing Windows folder): http://superuser.com/questions/319205/mounting-a-remote-windows-drive-on-a-local-windows-machine/319211 And here a dicussion of why it is usually a bad idea: http://serverfault.com/questions/108193/mount-network-drive-as-physical-drive